# "Як рак на горі свисне"

Tags: фразеологізми

*"Як рак на горі свисне"* - означає ніколи.
Чи існують ще якісь фразеологізми для слова "ніколи"?

Comment: Ви google'ити пробували?

Comment: @Sasha так, я знову припустилася помилки при оформлені питання. Я знайшла: "як виросте гарбуз на вербі" та "як виросте трава на помості"

Comment: «„Як виросте гарбуз на вербі“ та „як виросте трава на помості“» — це дуже добре. Якщо Ви пам'ятаєте, де Ви їх бачили (адреси сайтів або авторів/назви/видавництва книжок), то Ви можете оформити це як відповідь, ввівши відповідну інформацію у полі «Your Answer» — це дуже заохочується. (Але якщо не пам'ятаєте джерела, то тоді оформлювати як відповідь не варто, бо тут доволі агресивно ставляться до відповідей без джерел.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Знайшла ще два варіанти фразеологізмів зі значенням *"ніколи"* на сайті [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/frazeologizmu/nikoly)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Варіанти:

- ніколи в світі¹
- доки/коли/поки/як рак свисне (на горі / на оборі)¹
- коли/швидше/як на долоні волосся виросте¹
- (не) бачити <чогось> мов/наче/немов/неначе/як власного/свого носа / власних/своїх вух¹

Джерела:

1. [«Ніколи» // «Словник фразеологічних синонімів» на rozum.org.ua](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=24&t=329).